# 403 Error when sending post request to external API

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdoodle

I have an Angular App that is used to compile a java program, I am using Jdoodle API for compilation, we send requests to Jdoodle and then get a response back, and that response is displayed over the UI. **In Postman everything works fine** but in the Spring boot app this gives me a 403 error.

**`Compilation` service class:**

```
package com.syn.service;

import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.syn.model.CompilationInputBean;
import com.syn.model.CompilationResultBean;
import com.syn.model.ResultOutput;
import com.syn.model.UserBean;
import com.syn.repository.ApplicantRepository;
import com.syn.repository.UserRepository;
import com.syn.testcases.Global_TestCases;

@Service
public class CompilationService {
    
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    ApplicantRepository applicantRepo;
    
    public CompilationResultBean compile(CompilationInputBean inputData) throws JSONException {
        int questionCode=1;
        String clientId = "e5ffc98dc2b5212ebd9c8899746ab5aa";
        String clientSecret = "7c2d0bf9be5478cbf96ae84569bf5cbcd9db99b2bb1b17470d9830b35da3c1b";
        String inputStr = inputData.getScript();
        String script = "import java.util.Arrays;public class Main{ public static void main(String[] args) {fizzbuzzProblem(6);}public static void fizzbuzzProblem(int n) {System.out.println(\\\"1\\\");}}";
        String language = inputData.getLanguage();
        String versionIndex = inputData.getVersionIndex();
        CompilationResultBean compilationResult = new CompilationResultBean();
        List<CompilationResultBean> list = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> outputList = new ArrayList<>();
        CompilationInputBean c = new CompilationInputBean();
        c.setClientId(clientId);
        c.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
        c.setLanguage(language);
        c.setScript(script);
        c.setVersionIndex(versionIndex);
        c.setStdin("10");

       ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
           
       for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
           try {
               URL url = new URL("https://api.jdoodle.com/v1/execute");
               HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
               connection.setDoOutput(true);
               connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
               connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");       
               String input ="";
               System.out.print(inputData.getQuestion()+"Hello");
               input = Global_TestCases.numberOfTestCasesPassed(input,inputData.getQuestion(), i , mapper,c);
               System.out.println(input);
               OutputStream outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
               outputStream.write(input.getBytes());
               outputStream.flush();

               if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                   throw new RuntimeException("Please check your inputs : HTTP error code : "+ connection.getResponseCode());
               }

               BufferedReader bufferedReader;
               bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
               (connection.getInputStream())));

               String output;
               StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
               
               while ((output = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                   System.out.println(output);
                   sb.append(output).append(" ");
               }
               String finalStr = sb.toString();               
               final JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(finalStr);
               compilationResult.setOutput(obj.getString("output"));
               compilationResult.setStatusCode(obj.getInt("statusCode"));
               list.add(compilationResult);
               outputList.add(compilationResult.getOutput());
               connection.disconnect();
               
           } 
           catch (MalformedURLException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
              
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
       long count =  Global_TestCases.casesPassed(outputList,inputData.getQuestion());
       list.get(0).setOutput(outputList.get(0));
       list.get(0).setNoOfTestCasesPassed(String.valueOf(count));
        return list.get(0);
    }
        
    public void resultCalculation(ResultOutput result) {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String email = userRepository.findByUsername(auth.getName()).get().getEmail(); 
        UserBean userBean = applicantRepo.findByEmail(email);
        float score = result.getPassedTC()*100/result.getTotalTC();
        userBean.setScorePercentage(score);
        applicantRepo.save(userBean);
    }
    
}
```

**`CompilationInputBean` class:**

```
    package com.syn.model;

public class CompilationInputBean {
    
    private String clientId;
    private String clientSecret;
    private String script;
    private String stdin;
    private String language;
    private String versionIndex;
    private String question;
    
    public String getScript() {
        return script;
    }
    public void setScript(String script) {
        this.script = script;
    }
    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }
    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        this.language = language;
    }
    public String getVersionIndex() {
        return versionIndex;
    }
    public void setVersionIndex(String versionIndex) {
        this.versionIndex = versionIndex;
    }
    public String getClientId() {
        return clientId;
    }
    public void setClientId(String clientId) {
        this.clientId = clientId;
    }
    public String getClientSecret() {
        return clientSecret;
    }
    public void setClientSecret(String clientSecret) {
        this.clientSecret = clientSecret;
    }
    public String getStdin() {
        return stdin;
    }
    public void setStdin(String stdin) {
        this.stdin = stdin;
    }
    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }
    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }
    

    
}
```

**`ApplicationController` **

```
@PostMapping("/user/compile")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
public CompilationResultBean compile(@RequestBody CompilationInputBean inputData) throws JSONException {
    return compilationService.compile(inputData);
}
```

**Complete `error` log:**

```
FizzBuzz problemHello{"clientId":"e5ffc98dc2b5212ebd9c8899746ab5aa","clientSecret":"7c2d0bf9be5478cbf96ae84569bf5cbcd9db99b2bb1b17470d9830b35da3c1b","script":"import java.util.Arrays;public class Main{ public static void main(String[] args) {fizzbuzzProblem(6);}public static void fizzbuzzProblem(int n) {System.out.println(\\\"1\\\");}}","stdin":"10","language":"java","versionIndex":"0","question":null}
2021-08-22 14:47:39.756 ERROR 8732 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Please check your inputs : HTTP error code : 403] with root cause

java.lang.RuntimeException: Please check your inputs : HTTP error code : 403
    at com.syn.service.CompilationService.compile(CompilationService.java:76) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.syn.security.ApplicationController.compile(ApplicationController.java:131) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.syn.security.ApplicationController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a7696031.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:69) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at com.syn.security.ApplicationController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ac6c3750.compile(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.syn.jwt.JwtAuthTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthTokenFilter.java:54) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1457) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_271]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_271]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_271]
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

**Full Code over Github:** https://github.com/vishwaratna/Synpulse_Online_portal

Comment: I would suggest you to compare the two request (postman, and the angular app). This will give you understanding if you are missing on some header value.

Comment: @ManishSoni have tried that comparison, but whenever I try to request from the spring project I get the 403 error. I have even override my spring security configuration but no luck. `@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().
                authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
        
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }`

Comment: Did you have a look at the response body? The `input` you're POSTing doesn't look like JSON…

Comment: Is this `"question":null` correct?

Comment: @LMC I have removed the `question` from the payload now, but still, the same error persists.

Comment: Hi @VishwaRatna, i tried to place your code in a spring boot project but i'm missing to many pieces. Can you maybe push a working demo on github where you get the 403 of your app so we can pull and debug it. I guess the problem is in your connection set-up to Jdoodle. I personally would use spring's Resttemplate/WebClient implementation to set-up a connection to Jdoodle.

Comment: @guicey I have made my project as public now: https://github.com/vishwaratna/Synpulse_Online_portal

Answer (score 1):

This is what I understand you are sending wrong data to the API.

```
OutputStream outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
           outputStream.write(input.getBytes());
```

You are sending `input` object as request.

But you should send the actual input which has script and language.

So you should write the actual object with script/code, in your case it is `c`

So please try to replace code with:
convert the object `c` into json string and then pass json string.

```
 OutputStream outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
                   outputStream.write(jsonStringOfC.getBytes());
```

Also if you can share **API documentation**, It will be easy to help.

Answer (score 1):

I checked out the jdoodle API, and even though it is not clear, I would say you have issues with your credentials. Perhaps a typo or you used up your credits. Can you please post the response of https://api.jdoodle.com/v1/credit-spent using your clientId and clientSecret?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about java (more in node.js) but 403 is a forbidden message which means that you might have not given the proper authorization

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending the post to the API, log it, then post it into a JSON validator such as https://jsonlint.com/.   You're not sending valid JSON, and you're getting a 403 access denied because of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn’t add user agent in header you may get this 403 error.

```
headers.add(“user-agent”, “Application”);
```